# Build a route pattern based on Controller type and Acton name

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, hateoas, hal

***Disclaimer***: First of all, I want to mention that I looked all over the internet for an answer, read all the documentation, read all the question I could possibly find here, but no luck so far.

So, here's my case. I am building an API using ASP.NET Core 2.2 and I'm using HATEOAS ([HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) specification and [Halcyon](https://github.com/visualeyes/halcyon) library). I should provide links along with the resource itself. This what drove me towards HATEOAS in the first place. Some of the links are templated, since it might be a `PUT` method and `id` is to be specified by frontend.

The issue is, that my controllers can have very different routes (using attribute-based routing) and hardcoding links is a bad thing,cause if the route changes I need to remember to change the link where it's used as well. For this reason I decided to generate link based on Controller type and Action name. LinkGenerator is what I found, but it seems it returns null, if I don't specify all the parameters for the route. Here's a code example:

```
[Route("api/metadata")]
[ApiController]
public class MetadataController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IMetadataProvider _metadataProvider;
    private readonly LinkGenerator _linkGenerator;

    public MetadataController(
        IMetadataProvider metadataProvider,
        LinkGenerator linkProvider)
    {
        _metadataProvider = metadataProvider;
        _linkGenerator = linkProvider;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetMetadata()
    {
        var metadata = _metadataProvider.GetMetadata();
        // here url will be 'null', because last parameter is null
        // and route requires parameter 'name' to be specified instead of 'null'
        // EXPECTED: "api/metadata/{name}"
        // ACTUAL: null
        string url = _linkGenerator.GetPathByAction(
            nameof(MetadataController.GetByName),
            nameof(MetadataController).Replace(nameof(Controller), string.Empty),
            null);

        var response = new HALResponse(metadata)
            .AddSelfLink(HttpContext.Request)
            .AddLinks(new Link(name, url));

        return Ok(response);
    }

    [HttpGet("{name}")]
    public IActionResult GetByName(string name)
    {
        var metadata = _metadataProvider.GetMetadataForEntity(name);
        return Ok(metadata);
    }
}
```

How can I generate a link, so that it's not hardcoded and it is templated?

Comment: I don't understand, why is my question voted to be closed? Seems like a case that is not described anywhere...

Comment: You should include some code in your question which describes exactly what you doing.

Answer (score 1):

After a couple of hours of debugging the ASP.NET source code, I think I found a way to do this.

It seems, that `LinkGenerator` is intended to build a complete and valid url, so all the parameters are required. What I was looking for was actually a **route pattern**.

While debugging, I found a `IEndpointAddressScheme<RouteValuesAddress>` service injected into `LinkGnerator`. It is used to actually **find the route patern**. After that, **LinkGenerator** tries to fill all the parameters.

Here's the above code fixed and working:

```
[ApiController]
public class MetadataController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IMetadataProvider _metadataProvider;
    private readonly IEndpointAddressScheme<RouteValuesAddress> _endpointAddress;

    public MetadataController(
        IMetadataProvider metadataProvider,
        IEndpointAddressScheme<RouteValuesAddress> endpointAddress)
    {
        _metadataProvider = metadataProvider;
        _endpointAddress = endpointAddress;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetMetadata()
    {
        var metadata = _metadataProvider.GetMetadata();
        // EXPECTED: "api/metadata/{name}"
        // ACTUAL: "api/metadata/{name}"
        string actionName = nameof(MetadataController.GetById);
        string controllerName = nameof(MetadataController).Replace(nameof(Controller), string.Empty);
        var url = _endpointAddress.FindEndpoints(CreateAddress(actionName, controllerName))
            .OfType<RouteEndpoint>()
            .Select(x => x.RoutePattern)
            .FirstOrDefault();;

        var response = new HALResponse(metadata)
            .AddSelfLink(HttpContext.Request)
            .AddLinks(new Link(name, url));

        return Ok(response);
    }

    [HttpGet("{name}")]
    public IActionResult GetByName(string name)
    {
        var metadata = _metadataProvider.GetMetadataForEntity(name);
        return Ok(metadata);
    }

    private static RouteValuesAddress CreateAddress(string action, string controller)
    {
        var explicitValues = new RouteValueDictionary(null);
        var ambientValues = GetAmbientValues(httpContext);

        explicitValues ["action"] = action;
        explicitValues ["controller"] = controller;

        return new RouteValuesAddress()
        {
            AmbientValues = ambientValues,
            ExplicitValues = explicitValues
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting the solution you found.